# Python Else not passing when IF fail to get json reponse

Tags: python, json, if-statement

```
        global JsonResponse      
    JsonResponse = response.json()['error']     
    if response.json()['error']:        
     print ("\n" + "Notice =" , (JsonResponse)) 
     
    else:
     sys.exit(Y+ "Account Created Successfully")
```

i can't pass with else result 'IF' always giving me KeyError: 'error'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print ("\n" + "Notice =" , (response.json()['error']))  if 'error' in JsonResponse.json() else sys.exit(Y+ "Account Created Successfully")
```

I've made it one line so it doesn't use "success"

Comment: yeah that what i want <3 but please edit this response.json() else "success"

Answer (score 0):

Could you first check if there is any response?
response.json() might be {}
So what you could do is:

```
if response.json():
    do_stuff
```

You could also do this:

```
if 'error' in response.json():
     do_stuff
```

Comment: there is no 'error' in json when account info is right

Comment: still getting     JsonResponse = response.json()['error']
KeyError: 'error'

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the `'error'` key does not exist for successful requests.  But you're using the `mydict['key']` syntax, which *requires* that the key exists.  If it doesn't, it throws an exception.

You should *ask* if the key exists, instead of *assuming* it exists.  You can do this with the `in` keyword:

```
if 'key' in mydict:
```